# Responsive menu issue from landscape to portrait

Tags: html, css

when I switch view from portrait to landscape my test website page looks fine. When I switch back it does not reset to how it first looked. Any ideas why?

http://www.dorsettourist.co.uk/places-to-visit/coy-pond/coy-pond.html

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
.menu-trigger {
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .menu-trigger {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgb(76,171,41);
    color:white;
  }
  div.menu {
    display:none;
  }
  div.menu-expanded { 
    display:block;width:100%
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "How it first looked?" I just tested it and didn't see any major differences.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot? When I am changing the size of my web browser on my computer everything seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Hi, when I view on a Samsung Galaxy mobile in portrait mode the top menu (home, places to visit etc) looks as it should. When I switch to landscape the top menu adjusts to fit the screen width. When I return to portrait the menu does not switch back to how it first looked. It seems to keep the landscape menu width. Sorry, finding it difficult to explain!

Comment: do you use a line `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"` within your css file????

Comment: Hi, I only use the meta name you mention in the HTML file